# While Loop in Python ( Beginner)

Tags: python, while-loop, passwords

Struggling with this one. Only a beginner so go easy on me! :)
Trying to have user input password and if not within 6-10 characters. They are asked to input again.
When password correct the loop stops.
I can’t seem to get it to exit the loop even if correct lenght password entered.!

```
min_password_lenght = 6
max_password_lenght = 10

password = input(“enter password:”)
password_lenght = len(password)

while password_lenght > 6 or password_lenght < 10:
          print(“error”)
          password = input(“enter again:”)

print (“password correct”)
```

Comment: You're going to need to paste the text version of your code in the body of your question, the image is near unreadable and is not the recommended way to ask a question.

Comment: You do not update `password_length` and check for the wrong range.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23294658/asking-the-user-for-input-until-they-give-a-valid-response

Answer (score 1):

You should probably be more specific next time, but here's a snippet that satisfies what you described:

```
pwd = ""
while len(pwd) < 6 or len(pwd) > 10:
    pwd = input("Enter password: ")
```

Comment: Or if you don't want to compute the length twice: `while not 6 <= len(pwd) <= 10:`